# Como criar uma lista em tempo real com PHP e Ajax

Tags: php, sql, ajax

Estou criando um site de receitas, onde os ingredientes serão cadastrados individualmente em uma tabela, fazendo referencia ao id da receita, exemplo de como estão as tabelas:

```
ptp_receitas
id|nome
1 |receita de feijão

ptp_receitas_ingredientes
id|id_receita|ingrediente
1 |    1     | feijão
2 |    1     | bacon
3 |    1     | cebola
```

Eu criei um formulário que insere os valores no banco de dados, mas não sei como fazer para inserir cada ingrediente em uma linha nova.

Pensei em algo com ajax, colocando um input "ingrediente" que vai adicionando os valores num select multiplo, e após cadastrar a receita, ele pega cada valor dessa lista e insere uma linha na ptp_receitas_ingredientes, algo assim:

```
<input id="ingrediente">
<button id="add_ingrediente" type="button">Adicionar Ingrediente</button>
<select id="ingredientes" multiple>
</select>
<input id="nome_receita">
<button id="cadastrar_receita" type="submit">Cadastrar Receita</button>
```

A linha de raciocínio para a minha necessidade é essa mesma? Ou tem outra forma de se fazer isso?

Obrigado!

Comment: Poste o php que você usa para inserir no banco, é necessário para formular uma resposta adequada

Answer (score 0):

A linha de raciocínio é simples. Sua estrutura de banco tem duas tabelas, sendo que uma tem uma chave estrangeira (FK) referenciando a outra em um relacionamento 1->n.

Para inserir estes registros, você terá que obrigatoriamente seguir a seguinte ordem dos INSERT's

1. INSERT na tabela "ptp_receitas"
2. Recupera o ID que acabou de ser inserido (existem várias formas de fazer isso, depende de quais tecnologias você está utilizando)
3. Faz os INSERT's na tabela "ptp_receitas_ingredientes" utiliando os dados recebidos do formulário e o ID recuperado anteriormente.

Nestes passos, cada INSERT realmente terá que ser executado individualmente.

Você pode enviar todos dados para o back-end e lá organizar as instruções INSERT que serão executadas ou pode faz uma requisição AJAX para cada instrução de modo serial, desde que respeite a ordem acima.